# How to make a CompletableFuture be recycle by garbage collection when it's completed?

Tags: java, completable-future

I built a task chain based on CompletableFuture of java, it could be very very long. My question is every task in CompletableFuture is an inner class `UniCompletion`, and it holds a reference to source CompletableFuture, so that it's impossible that completed CompletableFuture be garbage collected. Is there a way to avoid memory leaks for that?

Here is a piece of code that can be used to reproduce this error:

```java
    public static void main(String... args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        AtomicReference<CompletableFuture<Integer>> future = new AtomicReference<>(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0));
        IntStream.range(0, 100000000).forEach(i -> future.set(future.get().thenApplyAsync(ii -> ii + 1, executor)));
        future.get().get();
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Comment: When the dependent action is running, the thread holds its reference, so GC do not recycle it. After that, a new action starting that depends on the above one and holds reference until it is finished. I have an action chain; the last action will hold reference of the first action, but I want the first `Future` to be recycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I use the follow program,

```
import java.lang.ref.Cleaner;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport;

public class CfGc {
    static final Cleaner CLEANER = Cleaner.create();
    static CompletableFuture<Integer> next(CompletableFuture<Integer> f) {
        Object[] status = { "not completed" };
        CLEANER.register(f, () -> System.out.println(status[0]+" future collected"));
        return f.whenComplete((i,t) -> {
                status[0] = t != null? t: i;
                LockSupport.parkNanos(500_000_000);
                System.out.println(status[0]+" completed, running gc()");
                System.gc();
                LockSupport.parkNanos(5_000_000);
                System.out.println(status[0]+" completed, gc() ran\n");
            }).thenApply(i -> i + 1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> s = new CompletableFuture<>(), f = s;
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) f = next(f);
        s.complete(1);
    }
}
```

it consistently prints on my machine

```
1 completed, running gc()
1 completed, gc() ran

2 completed, running gc()
2 completed, gc() ran

3 completed, running gc()
2 future collected
3 completed, gc() ran

4 completed, running gc()
3 future collected
4 completed, gc() ran

5 completed, running gc()
4 future collected
5 completed, gc() ran

6 completed, running gc()
5 future collected
6 completed, gc() ran
```

This demonstrates that the future is reachable while its subsequent stage is evaluated, but not during the evaluation of the stage after next. It’s not like the entire chain was kept referenced until the last stage finished.

Only the first future stays reachable, which is unavoidable in the sequential evaluation of the chain, as everything happens in the `complete` method invoked from the `main` method on the first future. When we change the program to

```
static final Cleaner CLEANER = Cleaner.create();
static CompletableFuture<Integer> next(CompletableFuture<Integer> f) {
    Object[] status = { "not completed" };
    CLEANER.register(f, () -> System.out.println(status[0]+" future collected"));
    return f.whenComplete((i,t) -> {
            status[0] = t != null? t: i;
            LockSupport.parkNanos(500_000_000);
            System.out.println(status[0]+" completed, running gc()");
            System.gc();
            LockSupport.parkNanos(5_000_000);
            System.out.println(status[0]+" completed, gc() ran\n");
        }).thenApplyAsync(i -> i + 1);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<Integer> s = new CompletableFuture<>(), f = s;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) f = next(f);
    s.complete(1);
    s = null;
    f.join();
}
```

it prints

```
1 completed, running gc()
1 completed, gc() ran

2 completed, running gc()
1 future collected
2 completed, gc() ran

3 completed, running gc()
2 future collected
3 completed, gc() ran

4 completed, running gc()
3 future collected
4 completed, gc() ran

5 completed, running gc()
4 future collected
5 completed, gc() ran

6 completed, running gc()
5 future collected
6 completed, gc() ran
```

on my machine, showing that the initial future can get garbage collected too when it is not referenced from a stack frame during the completion.

The same applies when we use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<Integer> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) f = next(f);
    f.join();
}
```

regardless of whether the `next` method uses `thenApply` or `thenApplyAsync`.

Comment: Thank you very much. And I added a piece of code that may be helpful in solving this problem. I will analyze the codes and try to identify the problem.

Comment: Your question was about the garbage collection of *completed* futures, but your example just creates new *uncompleted* futures faster than the asynchronous completion, which may cause an `OutOfMemoryError` unless the garbage collector slows down the application threads. That’s a problem you can’t solve; as long as the futures are not completed and there’s an ongoing completion attempt, they can’t get garbage collected. Just slowing down the creation, e.g. by inserting `.peek(i -> LockSupport.parkNanos(1))`, so the completion can catch up, would make the example run smoothly.