# Will infinite chain of CompletableFuture be garbage collected?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, future, completable-future

I am using `CompletableFuture` to publish events. Since there is a requirement that the order of the events need to be maintained, I am chaining them by key using `thenCompose`. I am concerned about garbage collection with such an approach using infinite chaining. Will additional calls maintain references to previous `CompletableFuture` and not allow for them to ever be garbage collected?

```
Map<Integer, CompletableFuture<EventResult>> eventFutureMap = new HashMap<>();

Publisher publisher;
    
public CompletableFuture<EventResult> publish(Event event) {
    CompletableFuture<EventResult> eventFuture;
        Integer key = event.getKey();
        CompletableFuture<EventResult> existingEvent = eventFutureMap.get(key);
        if (existingEvent != null) {
            eventFuture = existingEvent.thenCompose((EventResult meta) -> publisher.publish(event));
        } else {
            eventFuture = publisher.publish(event);
        }
        eventFutureMap.put(key, eventFuture);
    return eventFuture;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile because you don't definitely assign `eventFuture`. Also, it doesn't really seem like you'd want a `ThreadLocal` holding `eventFutureMap`, then you'd only chain if you _happened_ to execute on the same thread.

Comment: You are correct. I made some errors when creating a MRE. In the previous example, chaining on the same thread only is the correct assumption. I have updated the example now to fit the question better.

Comment: Re, `ThreadLocal`. Just don't use it! `ThreadLocal` can be a help sometimes when you are porting an old, thread-unsafe library to a multi-threaded environment. If the library keeps state in `static` variables, you can make them all `static ThreadLocal`, and then each thread that uses the library can have its own library state, unaffected by other threads using the library. Otherwise, `ThreadLocal` is not much use. It usually only makes sense for `static` variables to be `ThreadLocal`, and there's plenty of good reasons not to use `static` in new code.

Comment: "...with such an approach using infinite chaining", infinite of _anything_ will result in a OOM, before you even closely reach infinity. Just code it like you want to code it, you will be 99.(9)% just fine.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Looking at the example above, how would you handle `publish` getting called from multiple threads then?

Comment: @Eugene I understand where you are coming from, but what I mean is, will chaining without letting all completion stages complete prevent garbage collection? Infinite of anything doesn't have to result in a OOM as long as objects can be garbage collected.

Comment: `eventFutureMap` in your original post was a `ThreadLocal` variable. That would seem to imply that you wanted each thread to have its own, independent state. I don't know why you would want that. You've only showed us a small bit of code--your proposed solution to a problem--but you've hardly given us any idea of what the problem actually is. It's hard for anybody to suggest a better way if they don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Generally speaking though, If I wanted some threads to each have their own private state object, then I would either have those state objects created in the constructor of the thread's `Runnable` delegate, or I would have other code create the state objects first, and then pass them in an argument to the `Runnable` delegate's constructor.

Comment: is your `eventFutureMap` really an instanced field? How entries are garbage collected depends on the lifetime of that map and what callers do with the result of `publish`.

Comment: I think, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61888541/2711488) is precisely answering your question. Besides that, there’s also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44530286/2711488) discussing the implementation detail of not holding additional references to the futures.

Comment: I think there is a lot of confusion in the comments about the usage of that map when the question is really about the chaining with `thenCompose()`. Assuming OP can properly deal with the map entries and related cleanup, we can remove the map entirely from the picture. At that point, the problem boils down to having a single `CompletableFuture` being replaced by a new one created via `thenCompose()`, in which case I also believe it is the same as the question linked (and answered) by @Holger.